# Bootstrap tags input with Bootstrap 3 typeahead error

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-typeahead, bootstrap-tags-input

I integrated [Bootstrap tags input](https://github.com/bootstrap-tagsinput/bootstrap-tagsinput) with [Bootstrap 3 Typeahead](https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead) putting data-provide on input field like this:

```
<input type="text" name="search" id="search" data-provide="typeahead" autocomplete="off">
```

And initialising it in my js file like:

```
$('#search').tagsinput({
    confirmKeys: [44],
    typeahead: {
        source: $.getJSON('/Functions/hints.php')
    }
});
```

Everything is working fine, hints.php sends json, typeahead works, tags work, but I have a problem when I try to add an item from a suggested list. For example I want to search for "clothes", I type in "cl" and "Clothes gets suggested, I choose that item from the "dropdown" list and it gets inserted as a tag but the problem is that "cl" stays in the input field and I get an error saying "TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'data[option].apply')".

I have also noticed that it works ok if I start entering a term that doesn't suggest anything (doesn't start the typeahead), it will be turned into a tag without a problem, and input is clear after it turns into a tag. I only get this error once the typeahead has been initialised. So I can enter non-suggesting words for as long as I want and it works ok, but once I type in a letter that gives me some suggestion from that point on I always get the mentioned error no matter if the letter is recognised and I get something suggested or not and if I choose the item from list or type in my own word.

I tried the fix mentioned by xplicit on this [link](https://github.com/bootstrap-tagsinput/bootstrap-tagsinput/issues/236), and I tried writing some custom code to clear the field but I always get some kind of error and can't clear the input field.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, it's too late, but I will answer anyway.

I have encountered the similar problem and used one workaround.

There is function in bootstrap-tagsinput.js, that update the list of tags and return a text to the typeahead (line 329):

```
      updater: function (text) {
        self.add(this.map[text]);
        return this.map[text];
      },
```

I don't know why, but it returns the text of tag to input field. So I just changed this code to:

```
      updater: function (text) {
        self.add(this.map[text]);
        return "";
      },
```

Not it works.